# Android mobile internet not working

Tags: connection-issues, mobile-data

On my phone I'm not able to access the internet. I have signal and data coverage. I still can't browse. But as soon as Mobile Hotspot is turned on, other devices can connect to the Internet and my device can connect to the Internet. It's a strange issue but it occurs often for me.

Is this an Android issue, a cell carrier issue, or a device issue? Thanks

Comment: i have same issue with my lenovo yoga tab 3 (android 6.0.1) tablet. did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Follow these instructions:

- Try a reboot and check the option in Phone Settings.
- Check if data roaming option is enabled.
- Mostly, access point settings are provided by the ISP. Still, crosscheck them.

  <sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

  [image: IMG: Roaming]

Following is the code to access detailed information about your phone and its network:

```
*#*#4636#*#*
```

Comment: I tried this but still its not working. Note the same device internet can be accessed through wifi hotspot from other devices.

Comment: Okay, open play store and download a new browser like Opera Mini.

Answer (score 0):

Clearing the Proxy/Port settings of active Access point name solved for me. see this QA:
[Mobile Data only working when used as hotspot](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/53560/mobile-data-only-working-when-used-as-hotspot?rq=1)